# php preg_split ignore comma in specific string

Tags: php, regex

I need some help. What I want is to make ignore a comma in specific string. It is a comma seperated file csv, but the name have a comma, and I need to ignore that.

What I got is

```
<?php
    $pattern = '/([\\W,\\s]+Inc.])|[,]/';
    $subject = 'hypertext language, programming, Amazon, Inc., 100';
    $limit = -1;
    $flags = PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE;
    $result = preg_split ($pattern, $subject, $limit, $flags);
    ?>
```

Result is

```
$result (php code):

<?php
array (
  0 => 'hypertext language',
  1 => ' programming',
  2 => ' Amazon',
  3 => ' Inc.',
  4 => ' 100',
);
?>
```

And I want the result to be

```
$result (php code):

    <?php
    array (
      0 => 'hypertext language',
      1 => ' programming',
      2 => ' Amazon, Inc.',
      3 => ' 100',
    );
    ?>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What is the rule you want to apply here? Match a `,` that is not followed with `Inc.`? Like [`/,(?!\s*Inc\.)/`](https://regex101.com/r/iZlamw/1)?

Comment: Thanks it works :)

Comment: `str_getcsv`, assuming your line is already formatted as CSV.

Comment: Where do you get that csv file from? If a field contains a separator it should be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: It's from finance.yahoo.com, where some of the company names is with comma. I use the tutorial from this website http://blog.chapagain.com.np/php-how-to-get-stock-quote-data-from-yahoo-finance-complete-code-and-tutorial/

Comment: If I download one of those files from the link provided in the blog, those fields are quoted correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `[\W,\s]` = `\W` since `\W` matches any char that is not a letter, digit or underscore. However, it seems you just want to split on a `,` that is not followed with space(s)*+`Inc.`.

You may use a [**negative lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to achieve this:

```
/,(?!\s*Inc\.)/
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iZlamw/1)

The `(?!\s*Inc\.)` will fail any `,` match if there are 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`) followed with a sequence of literal characters `Inc.` after them.

Answer (score 1):

From your tutorial, if I pull the Amazon information as a CSV, I get the following format.  Which you can then parse with one of Php's native functions.  This shows you don't need to use explode or regex to handle this data. Use the right tool for the job:

```
<?php
$csv =<<<CSV
"amzn","Amazon.com, Inc.",765.56,"11/2/2016","4:00pm","-19.85 - -2.53%",10985
CSV;

$array = str_getcsv($csv);

var_dump($array);
```

Output:

```
array (size=7)
  0 => string 'amzn' (length=4)
  1 => string 'Amazon.com, Inc.' (length=16)
  2 => string '765.56' (length=6)
  3 => string '11/2/2016' (length=9)
  4 => string '4:00pm' (length=6)
  5 => string '-19.85 - -2.53%' (length=15)
  6 => string '10985' (length=5)
```